# Take a value from html and update DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic webpage (not connected to a server) which takes information in a form and displays this information on the same page. One of the input options is a checkbox and I am struggling to display these selected values on the page. I've been unable to decipher the other solutions I've come across. There's a lot of text below but it's pretty basic.

What do I need to display the results of the checkbox selections? Are the results of a checkbox input saved in an array?

Any assistance will be of great use.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const newItem = document.querySelector('#new-item');
  newItem.addEventListener('submit', handleNewItemForm);
})

const handleNewItemForm = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const whiskyItem = createWhiskyListItem(event.target);
  const whiskyList = document.querySelector('#drunk-whiskies');
  whiskyList.appendChild(whiskyItem);

  event.target.reset();
}

const createWhiskyListItem = function (form) {
  const whiskyItem = document.createElement('li');
  whiskyItem.classList.add('drunk-whiskies-item');

  const name = document.createElement('h2');
  name.textContent = form.name.value;
  whiskyItem.appendChild(name);

  const type = document.createElement('h3');
  type.textContent = form.type.value;
  whiskyItem.appendChild(type);

/**** This is the problem area. As above, I am looking to take the
 values from the form, make this into some text, before appending this
 to whiskyItem, which is then appended to whiskyList.
*/

  return whiskyItem;
}
```

```html
<form id="new-item">
  <div id="form-wrapper">

    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="name" class="primary">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="type" class="primary">Type</label>
      <input type="text" id="type" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="flavour" class="primary">What did you taste?</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="flavourProfile" value="boozy" name="boozy" checked>
      <label for="boozy">Booze</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="flavourProfile" value="malty" name="malty">
      <label for="malty">Malt</label>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
<h1>You've consumed...</h1>
<div id="drunk-whiskies"></div>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: "_I have a basic webpage (not connected to a server)_" In that case you don't have a webpage ... If there's no server, why do you have a submit button?

Comment: Just to accept the information added to the form

Comment: Hmm ... there seems to be more code. Now, the problem is the non-unique `id`s in the document, use a class to identify the checkboxes. Also appending `li` element to a `div` creates invalid HTML, the `li` should be appended into the list you have in your HTML. Whether a check box is checked or not, you can check from `checked` property of the each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have Same ID's values for both checkboxes, which is incorrect. Change the ID's values to "flavourProfile1' and 'flavourProfile2' respectively. And try the following code. It will display the selected checkbox value in the `<div id='drunk-whiskies'></div>`.

```
    $("#flavourProfile1").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) $("#drunk-whiskies").append('Booze');
    });

  $("#flavourProfile2").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) $("#drunk-whiskies").append('Malt');
    });
```

Comment: Not bad, not quite the approach I'd take, but mainly OP is using plain JS and has not tagged the question with _jquery_

Comment: You are right. But at least he could know that 10 line of code can avoid 100 line of code. That the beauty of libraries and frameworks.